# when is BLUETOOTH_ADMIN android permission required

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-permissions

I read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html that :

> If you want your app to initiate device discovery or manipulate Bluetooth settings, you must also declare the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission

What I think is that methods like

> cancelDiscovery()
>
> isDiscovering()
>
> startDiscovery()

requires the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission.

Are there any other methods that requires this permission?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Searching the codebase for `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/search?q=bluetooth_admin&defs=&refs=&path=java%2Fandroid%2Fbluetooth%2F&hist=&project=frameworks) reveals many places where it is documented.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static final String BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
```

Allows applications to discover and pair bluetooth devices

Constant Value: "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"

As you can see, everything that has to do with pairing and discovering of bluetooth devices

Comment: Does this include **BLE** pairing?